# fluent-bit to GCP through VPN tunnel

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, logging, fluentd, fluent-bit

I have an on-prem 4 nodes k8s cluster. There is VPN tunnel between mikrotik router and GCP subnet so GCP VM's and 4 on-prem nodes can communicate. I want to send logs from k8s cluster to one particular GCP bucket and be able to see logs in Log Viewer. I know that I need an agent eg. fluent-bit, and GCP sink configured to filter logs sent from on-prem cluster. The thing is that I want these logs go through VPN tunnel. How to achive this goal? Do you have any idea?

Comment: First question, why do you want to route logging traffic over a VPN? Google provides private access to all APIs and services. This means you must use Google internal addresses instead of public addresses. This sounds simple but can become complicated in on-prem systems. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-service-connect-apis and  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options

Comment: Security requirement. If I understand correctly - when sending logs to cloud logging public address is used by default. It can be changed to internal address but as you said can be compilcated in on-prem.

Comment: By following this [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/adding-a-tunnel) and [Connect your on-prem DC to Google Cloud with Cloud VPN](https://blog.searce.com/connect-your-on-prem-dc-to-google-cloud-with-cloud-vpn-edc0bd27657d) by Dimas Toscanni you can configure VPN Tunnel.

Comment: If you are getting any errors follow this [troubleshoot shoot doc](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/support/troubleshooting). Just a note that if you send the continuous logs through the VPN tunnel it may affect the performance and also the tunnel should need enough bandwidth to handle the request refer to this [network bandwidth doc](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#network-bandwidth).

Comment: @HemanthKumar I have a VPN tunnel established between on-prem and vpc GCP. Fluent-bit sends logs to Cloud Logging API which hmm is not a part of VPC network. So the traffic is not going through vpn tunnel. So my question is, is it possible to communicate with Cloud Logging API through VPN tunnel.

Comment: Yes , it is possible but you have to configure the routing rules correctly on your on prem-network to cloud logging API. refer to the docs suggested by @JohnHanley .

Comment: @RedBluff - Just changing stuff to an internal address will not work by itself. As I hinted setting up hybrid environments is a lot more than just having a working VPN. Did you read both document links I provided? You mentioned "security requirement". Traffic to Cloud Logging is encrypted, I am not sure what benefit redirecting that traffic will provide without a clear answer. Instead, I see a lot of potential problems that will decrease availability and security unless you know exactly what you are doing. Losing logs is a security vulnerability.

Comment: @RedBluff : is your issue resolved?. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.